# if(select column from table where column = :var_input from table)? wouldn't work :(

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I'm sorry but I've no idea how should I use if, end statement from the pl/SQL

this is the code i hope it explains what I want it to do

```
DECLARE 

        S1 NUMBER(2) := :ID;
        S2 VARCHAR2(32) := :USERNAME;
        S3 VARCHAR(32)  := :PASSWORD;
        X  VARCHAR2(300);
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
        VALUES (S1,S2,S3);
      COMMIT;

    IF((SELECT USERNAME FROM TEST1 WHERE USERNAME = S2) =S2 )
        THEN
        X:= SHOW_ALERT('ALERT12');
         IF (X=ALERT_BUTTON1)
             THEN EXIT_FORM;
         END IF;
    END IF;  

    END;
```

Comment: @Gauravsa , compiled successfully, well done!  :)

Comment: Although what gauravsa has put below will work, why would you want to do this?  If the insert works then the if statement will always return true, if the insert statement does not work then it will have thrown an error (that you are not catching) so will never get to the if statement

Comment: @ShaunPeterson, tbh, I'm working on it, I'll update it once I finished. I was just confused about the syntax of creating the if-statement in pl/SQL. I work before with c# and Matlab so I'm a little bit not sure of what I'm doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE 

    S1 NUMBER(2) := :ID;
    S2 VARCHAR2(32) := :USERNAME;
    S3 VARCHAR(32)  := :PASSWORD;
    X  VARCHAR2(300);
    v_count number;

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
    VALUES (S1,S2,S3);
  COMMIT;
 SELECT Count(*) into v_count FROM TEST1 WHERE USERNAME = S2;
IF(v_count = 1 )
    THEN
    X:= SHOW_ALERT('ALERT12');
     IF (X=ALERT_BUTTON1)
         THEN EXIT_FORM;
     END IF;
END IF;  

END;
```